# Must a counterexample $f$ to the $n$-dimensional JC satisfy $\cap f^i(k[x_1,\ldots,x_n])=k$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, jacobian-conjecture

There is a known result concerning the two-dimensional Jacobian Conjecture which says the following: Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero.
If $f:k[x,y] \to k[x,y]$ has an invertible Jacobian and is not an automorphism, then $\cap f^i(k[x,y])=k$; see the paper of [V. Shpilrain and J.-T. Yu](https://www.jstor.org/stable/118162?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents). Another proof, but for $k=\mathbb{C}$, is due to [H. Kraft](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242434791_On_a_Question_of_Yosef_Stein).

I am not able to generalize the proof of Shpilrain and Yu to $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$,
since, for example, when $n=3$, although two of $\{x,y,z\}$ can be assumed not in the image of $f$, but one of the three can be in the image, and then the infinite intersection can be strictly bigger than $k$; for example, if $f(x_1)=x_1$,
then $\cap f^i(k[x_1,\ldots,x_n])\supseteq k[x_1]$.

> Is it possible to generalize Kraft's proof to $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$?
>   (and where he uses algebraic closedness of the base field?).

I guess that proving a generalized version may not be easy, since otherwise probably Kraft would have mentioned how to generalize his result.

**Edit:** **(1)** As mentioned in to the comment, for a fixed $n$ I am asking about, further assume that JC holds for smaller dimensions than $n$ (otherwise the answer is easy).

**(2)** Based on the proof of Shpilrain and Yu in dimension two, it seems that in dimension $n \geq 3$ it is possible to show that there exist $n-2$ variables, w.l.o.g. $x_1,\ldots,x_{n-2}$, such that 
$\cap f^i(k[x_1,\ldots,x_n])\subseteq k[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-2}]$.

Comment: It seems to me that, if $(x,y) \mapsto (f(x,y), g(x,y))$ were a counterexample to the 2-dimensional Jacobian conjecture, and we define $h(x,y,z) = (f(x,y), g(x,y), z)$, then $z \in \bigcap_i h^i k[x,y,z]$. Maybe you would like to assume that JC holds for all dimensions less than $n$?

Comment: Good comment. I will add your assumption to my question.